# What does this としています express?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180127/k10011304581000.html

The sentence in question:

> 厚生労働省は「人手不足や景気の回復を背景に、留学生のアルバイトや技能実習生の活用が進んでいる」**としています**。

My attempt at translation:
"Concerning the ministry of health, labour and welfare, they decide that the application of foreign students side-jobs and technical trainees for the labour shortage and support of business recovery is voluntary."

I asked about a lot of と constructions recently and Im already a bit paranoid that I stumble across the same mistakes again, but I cant help it. I *think* that I got it right here, since I looked up "to decide to" on jisho and I think that it fits the context. But Im not sure ^^ A と B する means "make A into B", as far as I remember, so this one "to decide to" is kind of contained in this more general interpretation. But nevertheless, Id like to confirm wether I got it right.^^

Answer (score 11):

「～～としています」, in this context, means "***to judge and conclude***" and it is frequently used in news reporting.  In plain words, it means "***to assume that ~~ is the case***".

In other words, the phrase is used to describe one's (current) opinion or analysis on a given matter.

> "It is 厚生労働省's (judgement and) conclusion that 人手不足や景気の回復を背景に、留学生のアルバイトや技能実習生の活用が進んでいる."

大辞林 gives the following definitions.

と∘する （連語）
〔格助詞「と」に動詞「する」の付いたもの〕
（１）そのように仮定する意を表す。「君がそこに居合わせた―∘する」
（２）**そう考える，そう判断する，という意を表す**。「これでよし―∘しよう」「その可能性もある―∘しなければならぬ」「目標達成は難しい―∘されている」「万葉集は和歌集の最初―∘されている」
（３）ちょうどそうしようとしている，の意を表す。「出かけよう―∘すると，きまって雨が降る」