# Is this volitional +とする?

Tags: grammar

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0202.html?utm_int=news_contents_news-closeup_002

The sentence in question:
"残念ながら八王子隕石と特定はできませんでしたが、研究グループは、引き続き八王子隕石の実態の解明に挑**みたいとしていて**、一般の市民に、自宅に隕石のような石がないか、情報提供を呼びかけています。"

My attempt at translation:
"Im afraid to say that concerning hachioji meteorite and the specification, though we cant do it the research group trying to continously try to tackle the elucidation of the true state of hachioji meteorite appeals to the general public  for the provision of information if there is a stone like a meteorite in the house."

I don't know what to make of this みたいとしていて. I read that "volitional+とする" means "to attempt to", but usually volitional form means the よう-forms. みたい is also somehow volitional, but I couldnt find anything whether it can act in analogy to ようform+とする

Comment: Related, maybe? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56323/9831

Comment: ^ @l'électeur えっ 違うの？　どうしようわかんないｗｗ　Edit: あ わかった　「挑もう」が volitional ね

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about parsing it this way:

> Sentence 1: （残念ながら）八王子隕石と特定はできませんでしたが、
>
> Sentence 2: 研究グループは、『引き続き八王子隕石の実態の解明に挑みたい』としていて、一般の市民に、（自宅に隕石のような石がないか、）情報提供を呼びかけています。

In Sentence 2,

Subject = 研究グループ the research group
Verb 1 = していて say
Verb 2 = 呼びかけています appeal

---

> 研究グループは、『引き続き八王子隕石の実態の解明に挑みたい』としていて

挑みたい is the desiderative form (たい-form) of 挑む.
と is quotative, and して(<する) means "They say...". This ～～とする is often used in news reporting.

---

> （残念ながら）八王子隕石**と**特定はできませんでしたが、

The と doesn't mean "and".
「XXをYYと特定する」 means "identify XX as YY", so 「XXをYYと特定(は)できませんでした/できなかった」 means "couldn't identify XX as YY".
"Unfortunately, they couldn't identify it (= the stone) as a Hachioji meteorite, but..."