# What is the difference between として and とする?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I realize that “として” and “とする” have vastly different meanings, so let’s give some specific examples.

> (1)東京都内に住む南アジア出身で40代のイスラム教徒（ムスリム）の女性が、警視庁の警察官から不当な任意聴取を受け、他人に氏名や住所などの個人情報を漏らされた**として**5日、都公安委員会に苦情を申し出たことが分かった。
>
> (2)警察側は後日、民事訴訟を起こす**とする**男性に女性と長女の氏名や年齢、住所などの個人情報を伝達。

Source: https://www.nikkansports.com/m/general/news/202107050001193_m.html?mode=all

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the regular differences between the ～て form and the 連体形?

Answer (score 2):

These Xとして and Xとする have essentially the same meaning, "to claim/say/report X".

- [What does this としています express?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56323/5010)
- [Is this volitional +とする?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56596/5010)

The difference is that として is the te-form and とする is the attributive form (i.e., modifies the following noun as a relative clause). In other words, として in the first sentence is "..., claiming X", whereas とする in the second sentence means "[a man] who claims X".