# たい form + としている

Tags: grammar

I found this construction, which I don't really understand, a couple of time, which make me asking myself if it's a set phrase or something:

> このスキー場は来月２日に２本のコースの営業を始め、本格的なシーズンを迎える12月下旬には10本のコースを利用できるようにし**たいとしています**

In every instance I found it (two or three, unfortunately I didn't noted the others and I don't remember them), it always were `たい + としている`; I know `たい` is the "I want" form, and the general meaning of the sentence seems to be "These ski resorts will begin selling [tickets] for two [ski] courses on the 2nd of next month, and by when the regular season comes in the last third of December they want to be able to use 10 courses".

`ようにする` is "To decide to do; To make an effort to", with `たい` it becomes "They want to make an effort to [have all 10 courses open]". The `としています` seems kinda useless, meaning that, if I'm right in my translation, I can understand it without that part. I know `とする` can have a ton of meanings (which I'm currently struggling with); it's "just" to make a `ている` form of a `たい` form, something like "Right now in this period they want to"?

Comment: Duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/what-does-this-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-express/56326#56326 ?