# What does ことになるとし signify here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

> なろう系と異世界ものはほぼ同じ意味となっており、「なろう」、「なろう小説」、「異世界転生系」、「異世界転生もの」とも呼ばれるが、杉本穂高は投稿サイト以外の商業作品でも上記のような枠組みを利用した作品は多く、
> その言葉は
> 「なろう系」よりも広い範囲を指すため*「異世界転生もの」の中で大きな勢力を持ったのが「なろう系」**ということになるとし**、広い意味で異世界へ行くオンライン小説作品をなろう系だとすると往時の作品群がインターネットに掲載されていたら該当する....

While I was reading this wiki article about なろう系 I came across this sentence. However I cannot seem to understand this ということになるとし. Does it mean if "we assume it became as such..."?

Answer (score 3):

Bということになる means *it follows that B/means B*. There is some 'precedent' A, implicitly or explicitly. For example,

- 明日雨だと大会は延期ということになる If it rains tomorrow, it follows that the competition will be put off
- 今日は妻が病気なので自分で家事をしなければならないということになる The fact that my wife is sick means that I have to do the chores.

とし is と＋する in 連用形. Here it means *to say, to conclude*. See the following question:

- [What does this としています express?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56323/45489)

For the sentence in question, the structure is 杉本穂高はAためBということになるとし, which would translate to *Hodaka Sugimoto says that since A, it follows that B*.

Comment: Since A it follows **that** B. Without "that" it sounds a bit weird.

Comment: Just to confirm, a more literal translation of the second sentence is: "If today I do the chores because my wife is sick, it follows that it can't be helped." Is this correct?

Comment: @x-yuri It is literally *Because today my wife is sick, it follows that I have to do the chores.* You are misreading which part ということ encapsulates. It is 自分...ならない. (Though it is ambiguous where 今日 spans over. I.e., *Today, because my wife is sick,...* is another possibility.)

Comment: Oh, I see, する in the cond. form (しなければ) mislead me. I thought, "ということ can't possibly encapsulate 2 clauses (自分で家事をしなければ and ならない), can it? As such it only encapsulates ならない." But I now see that for ならない to mean "cannot help" it should supposedly be preceded by a verb in the て form. Instead the other meaning applies here, a verb V in the cond. neg. + ならない means "must V." So a simple explanation is that ということ encapsulates only one clause. Is there possibly a complex (more detailed) explanation that states that ということ indeed encapsulates 2 clauses, and why the 2 clauses mean what they mean?

Comment: encapsulate 2 clauses - you can. It is just a matter of meaning here. Wife being sick is a direct cause for having to do the chores. For example, 妻が妊娠した。しばらく働けないので我が家の収入は減るということになる。 would be *Wife got pregnant. It means that since she can't work for a while, our household income will decrease*. Here ということ encapsulates しばらく・・・減る.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically "assume it became as such" is not far off, but if you went with "we assume" because you saw the subject as implicit/empty, I think that is wrong. とし's base form is とする, and its subject is 杉本穂高は. The larger structure looks like: "Sugimoto Hotaka considers that there are many ..., that the term signifies ..., and that it follows that ...".

The quote is apparently from https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E7%B3%BB and it is a bit convoluted sentence. I would split it into shorter sentences.